# How to set the value for Radio Buttons When edit?

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I have a Gender Row with radio buttons male & female. when i register as first time the values of radio button will store in database. Now my question is if i edit that row again it want to come(that means checked) with that value as male/female. how to make it?

Note : Doing with php.

HTML Script :

```
<tr id="inside">
<td align="right" width="40%" id="side" >Gender</td>
<td width="3%"> </td>
<td align="left" width="50%">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" size="17">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" size="17">Female
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you have an PHP code executed before this HTML is rendered? An code which takes the value of `sex` from the DB perhaps?

Comment: HTML is actually a markup language and not a scripting language. You wrote this word 'HTML Script :'

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When you populate your fields, you can check for the value:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" <?php echo ($sex=='Male')?'checked':'' ?>size="17">Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" <?php echo ($sex=='Female')?'checked':'' ?> size="17">Female
```

Assuming that the value you return from your database is in the variable `$sex`

The checked property will preselect the value that match

Comment: Such an awesome solution, even ~two years on. Gotta love SO and its members.

Comment: @a7omiton I am glad the answer is still relevant :)

Answer (score 2):

just add 'checked="checked"' in the correct radio button that you would like it to be default on. As example you could use php quick if notation to add that in:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" size="17" <?php echo($isMale?'checked="checked"':''); ?>>Male
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" size="17" <?php echo($isFemale?'checked="checked"':''); ?>>Female
```

in this example $isMale & $isFemale is boolean values that you assign based on the value from your database.

Answer (score 2):

This is easier to read for me:

```
<input type="radio" name="rWF" id="rWF" value=1  <?php if ($WF == '1') {echo ' checked ';} ?> />Water Fall</label>
<input type="radio" name="rWF" id="rWF" value=0 <?php if ($WF == '0') {echo ' checked ';} ?> />nope</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Gender :<br>
    <input type="radio" name="g" value="male"  <?php echo ($g=='Male')?'checked':'' ?>>male <br>
    <input type="radio" name="g" value="female"<?php echo ($g=='female')?'checked':'' ?>>female
            <?php echo $errors['g'];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who might be in need for a solution in pug template engine and NodeJs back-end, you can use this:

If values are not boolean(IE: true or false), code below works fine:

```
input(type='radio' name='sex' value='male' checked=(dbResult.sex ==='male') || (dbResult.sex === 'newvalue') )
input(type='radio' name='sex' value='female' checked=(dbResult.sex ==='female) || (dbResult.sex === 'newvalue'))
```

If values are boolean(ie: true or false), use this instead:

```
input(type='radio' name='isInsurable' value='true' checked=singleModel.isInsurable || (singleModel.isInsurable === 'true') )
input(type='radio' name='isInsurable' value='false' checked=!singleModel.isInsurable || (singleModel.isInsurable === 'false'))
```

the reason for this || operator is to re-display new values if editing fails due to validation error and you have a logic to send back the new values to your front-end

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your values from a database table and creating radio buttons dynamically, here is the solution. The database records are fetched into an array in this example and used for creating radio buttons.

```
<?php foreach ($dbrecords as $item) : ?>
<div class="form-check  form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="paymentMethod" id="paymentMethod" value=<?php echo $item["Id"]; ?> <?php echo ($paymentMethod == $item["Id"]) ? 'checked' : '' ?>><?php echo $item["Name"]; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" <? if($gender=='Male')
{?> checked="" <? }?>/>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="female" <? if($gender=='Female') {?> checked="" <?}?>/>Female<br/> </td>
```