# How do I make a radio button selected by reading the value from my database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I have a form with some radio buttons, a textfield and a textarea which I insert into my database. Now I have an option to edit the the whole thing. When I click on a button edit I get the form again and the values in the textfield and textarea are the same I inserted into the database. Now I have no idea how I get the radio button with the right value as the value in the database checked.

This is my form:

```
<<<EOT
            <table>
  <form action="index.php?page=artikelen_bewerken_verwijderen&id={$_GET['id']}" method="post"> 
  <tr><th><td><input type="text" size="108%" name="title" value="{$titel}"></td></tr></th> 
  <tr><th><td> <textarea name="description"  rows="20" cols="80" >{$nieuwsbericht}</textarea></td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input type="radio" name="club"  value="borussia-dortmund">Borussia Dortmund </td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input type="radio" name="club"  value="ajax">Ajax</td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input type="radio" name="club" value="ac-milan">AC Milan</td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input type="radio" name="club"  value="fc-bayern">Bayern Munchen</td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input type="radio" name="club"  value="feyenoord">Feyenoord</td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input type="radio" name="club" value="juventus">Juventus</td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input type="radio" name="club"  value="real-madrid">Real Madrid</td></tr></th>
  <tr><th><td><input type="radio" name="club"  value="fc-barcelona">Barcelona</td></tr></th>   
  <tr><th><td><input name="edit" type="submit" value="Edit"></td></tr></th> 
  </form> 
 </table>
EOT;
```

Does anyone know how to get the radio button checked like I want to?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197377/how-to-set-the-value-for-radio-buttons-when-edit

Comment: @Whitebird thanks. Couldn't find it!

Comment: These things happen! That's why there's a comment system :).

Comment: @Whitebird Still can't manage to get it work.

Comment: @Whitebird well there is no error but I am using <<<EOT for my form and I dont want to end my EOT the whole time and start it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to prase the whole thing to an json array and let javascript do the thing.

If there can be only one radio button selected:

```
var radio_checked = '<?php echo $row['club']; ?>';

$(document).ready(function() { // start this when site is fully loaded
    if (radio_checked) { // check if variable is empty or not
        $(':radio[value='+radio_checked+']').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Or if there is more than one radio button checked (I assume you convert the result to an array in PHP):

```
var radio_array = <?php echo json_encode($yourArray); ?>;   

$(document).ready(function() { // start this when site is fully loaded
    if(!$.isArray(radio_array) || !radio_array.length) { // check if array is empty or not
        for (index in radio_array) {
            $(':radio[value='+radio_array[index]+']').prop('checked', true);
        }
    }
});
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, there is a pure PHP way, but this requires coding every time:

```
<input type="radio" name="club" <?php echo ($row['club'] == 'borussia-dortmund')? 'checked' : ''; ?> value="borussia-dortmund">
<input type="radio" name="club" <?php echo ($row['club'] == 'ajax')? 'checked' : ''; ?> value="ajax">
```

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Get the value from your database and crosscheck it with the value of the radio button. If they match, add a 'checked' attribute to your radio.

```
<input type="radio" name="club" value="borussia-dortmund" <?= ($valueFromDatabase == 'borussia-dortmund') ? 'checked' : ''?>>
```

Answer (score -1):

assume your mysql result array is: $row, assume your radio button index is: radio,now $row['radio'] it's your radio button reading from database,Place condition for checked or unchecked as following

```
<input type="radio" <?php if($row['radio']==1){?> 'checked' <?php } ?>/>

Let me know if you want more..
```

Comment: It's best to provide an exact code snippet to see it in action.