# Change radio button action as per database

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, css

How can I change the action of the radio button as per I getting value from the database. If I get gender value is male from the database it should be select male if I will get female radio button must be check as a female.

Comment: Possible Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197377/how-to-set-the-value-for-radio-buttons-when-edit

Answer (score 0):

This snippet solves the issue of updating the radios. You still need to figure out how to populate the `var data`

Happy coding!

```js
var data = {gender: 'female'};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=gender]');
  if (inputs && inputs.length) {
    inputs.forEach(function(inputElement) {
      if (inputElement.value === data.gender) {
        inputElement.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
        break;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
Male: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />
Female: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />
```