# check a radio button based on value retrieved from database

Tags: php

I have radio buttons that want to check if value retrieved from database is 'Yes'.
on this same forum a same question is there but after trying that and still no success. also i can't comment there anything about my question because i don't have sufficient reputation.
link to the question same as mine is:
[How to set the value for Radio Buttons When edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197377/how-to-set-the-value-for-radio-buttons-when-edit)

Below is the Form code which displays fetched data:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$server="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="camouflage_studio";

$con = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Connection Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
//receiving CINC from search form and getting record on it's basis
$cnic = $_POST['search'];
$data = "SELECT * FROM personal_detail WHERE CNIC='$cnic'";
if($query = mysqli_query($con, $data)){
      $data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query);  //i think it's used for to know the total number of rows fetched/retrieved 
}else{ echo "Query Not Executed!";}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Camouflage Studio - Welcome</title>
<!-- My CSS coding starts here -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- form to display Retrieved/Fetched data-->
<center>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
<fieldset style="width:50%"><legend>Please do the required changes</legend><br>
<label for="Name">Name :<br></label><input name="name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $data2[Name]?>"><br>
<label for="CNIC">CNIC :<br></label><input name="cnic" type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $data2[CNIC]?>"><br>
<label for="Date">Booking Date :<br></label><input name="booking-date" type="date" size="20" value="<?php echo $data2[Date]?>"><br>

<!-- <label for="Ocassion">Ocassion :<br></label> -->
<label for="Ocassion">Ocassion :<br></label><input name="ocassion" type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" value="<?php echo $data2[Ocassion]?>"><br>

<label for="Address">Address :<br></label><input name="address" type="text" size="20" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $data2[Address]?>"><br>

<label for="Phone Number">Phone Number :<br></label><input name="phone-no" type="text" size="20" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $data2[Phone_No]?>"><br>
<label for="Bride Mobile">Bride Mobile :<br></label><input name="bride-mobile" type="number" size="20" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $data2[Bride_Mobile]?>"><br>
<label for="Groom Mobile">Groom Mobile :<br></label><input name="groom-mobile" type="number" size="20" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $data2[Groom_Mobile]?>"><br>
<label for="Family Mobile">Family Mobile :<br></label><input name="family-mobile" type="number" size="20" maxlength="11" value="<?php echo $data2[Family_Mobile]?>"><br>
<label for="Email">Email :<br></label><input name="email" type="text" size="20" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $data2[EMail]?>"><br>
<label for="Who may I Thank for Refering You?">Who may I Thank for Refering You? :<br></label><input name="refering" type="text" size="20" maxlength="40" value="<?php echo $data2[Referring]?>"><br>
<label for="Do you provide consent to share images on our official web page">Do you provide consent to share images on our official web page? :<br><br></label><input type="radio" name="share" <?php echo ($data2[Share]=='Yes')?'checked':'' ?> value="Yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="share" <?php echo ($data2[Share]=='Yes')?'checked':'' ?> value="No">No<br><br>
<label for="If yes, with Identity">If yes, with Identity? :<br><br></label><input type="radio" name="permission" <?php echo ($data2[Permission]=='Yes')?'checked':'' ?> value="Yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="permission" <?php echo ($data2[Permission]=='Yes')?'checked':'' ?> value="No">No<br><br>
<!-- To center the button i'm embedding the buttons in a paragraph with an id as well. the id is used for CSS in head -->
<p id="btn">
<input type="submit" value="Update Record" name="submit_display_data_form" style="font-size:16px"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="share" <?php echo ($data2[Share]=='Yes')?'checked':'' ?> value="No">` Your code looks good (i don't get why you want to check it when your data is "Yes" as your radio value is "No" but still). Can you show us the HTML rendered ? are you sure your "checked" is echoed ? You should echo 'checked="checked"' instead of simply 'checked' but anyway both should work.

Comment: I uses three pages. one page to get the primary key value from user and get a record based on that key. that page (first one which contains the search field) calls another one (the above one) which displays the data in a form. the third page is under development which will update the data from the form but at this stage i'm not getting the correct data from the database, so i don't want to proceed to the updating page.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML rendered ? are you sure your "checked" is displayed in source code ?

Comment: HTML rendered means? almost i'm getting opposite results of my expectations.

Comment: Right clic, view page source... or CTRL+U...

Comment: <label for="Do you ...">Do you provide consent to share images on our official web page? :<br><br></label><input type="radio" name="share" checked value="Yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="share" checked value="No">No<br><br>
<label for="If yes, with Identity">If yes, with Identity? :<br><br></label><input type="radio" name="permission"  value="Yes">Yes<br>
<input type="radio" name="permission"  value="No">No<br><br>
<!-- To center the button i'm embedding the buttons in a paragraph with an id as well. the id is used for CSS in head -->
<p id="btn">

Comment: You have a serious SQL-Injection vulnerability in your code. Never ever use variables directly in SQL. Bad guys can use it to take over your database. Please learn about stored procedures and value binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Share = 'Yes';
$Permission = 'Yes';
    <label for="Do you provide consent to share images on our official web page">
        Do you provide consent to share images on our official web page? :
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="share" <?php echo ($Share =='Yes')? 'checked':'' ?> value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="share" <?php echo ($Share =='No')? 'checked':'' ?> value="No">No<br><br>

    <label for="If yes, with Identity">If yes, with Identity? :<br><br></label>
    <input type="radio" name="permission" <?php echo ($Permission=='Yes')?'checked':'' ?> value="Yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="permission" <?php echo ($Permission=='No')?'checked':'' ?> value="No">No<br><br>
```

Comment: $data2[Share] here $data2 is the variable that contains a RECORD retrieved from DATABASE. SHARE is the name of that COLUMN which can have YES or NO value. now when a record is fetched, and the value of SHARE is YES, then it's corresponding radion should be CHECKED, same for PERMISSION as well...

Comment: But for both permission and share you are using same condition for yes and no please check in your code  $data2['share] == "yes" for no and yes

Comment: For permission 
($data2['Permission']=='Yes')?'checked':''
($data2['Permission']=='No')?'checked':''

Use same like share also

Comment: Use This <input type="radio" name="share" <?php echo ($data2[Share]=='Yes')?'checked':'' ?> value="Yes">Yes<br> <input type="radio" name="share" <?php echo ($data2[Share]=='No')?'checked':'' ?> value="No">No<br><br> If yes, with Identity? :<br><br><input type="radio" name="permission" <?php echo ($data2[Permission]=='Yes')?'checked':'' ?> value="Yes">Yes<br> <input type="radio" name="permission" <?php echo ($data2[Permission]=='No')?'checked':'' ?> value="No">No<br><br>

Comment: brother i want the RADIO to be CHECKED ONLY if the $data2[Share] has 'Yes' as fetched VALUE. if NO is retrieved then i don't want the RADIO to be CHECKED. Same for Permission as well.

Comment: then remove the condition for second radio which have value NO

Comment: "For permission ($data2['Permission']=='Yes')?'checked':'' ($data2['Permission']=='No')?'checked':'' Use same like share also" this is right. you helped me. Thanks a lot

Comment: I was a little wrong in my logic. Your guided me correctly but at that time couldn't understand you. thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what value will be stored in `$_POST['key1']`.
If nothing is checked, $_POST['key1'] doesn't exist : `!isset($_POST['key1']) ;`
If first radio is checked, `$_POST['key1'] = 'Yes' ;`
If second radio is checked, `$_POST['key1'] = 'No' ;`
If you want to pre-check "No" when nothing is checked, you should test if the data does not exist or if the value is anything except 'Yes'.

In that way, you're sure that you will have 'Yes' or 'No' after submitting the form.

```
<input type="radio" name="key1" value="Yes" <?php if ( isset($data['key1']) && $data['key1'] == 'Yes' ) echo 'checked' ; ?> />

<input type="radio" name="key1" value="No" <?php if ( ! isset($data['key1']) || $data['key1'] !== 'Yes' ) echo 'checked' ; ?> />


<input type="radio" name="key2" value="Yes" <?php if ( isset($data['key1']) && $data['key2'] == 'Yes' ) echo 'checked' ; ?> />

<input type="radio" name="key2" value="No" <?php if ( ! isset($data['key1']) || $data['key2'] !== 'Yes' ) echo 'checked' ; ?> />
```